# Reputation summary badge is not calculated correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

The "badge" number appearing next to the "reputation" tab title on a user's profile is not calculated correctly. It ignores the *removed* category of reputation gains and losses.

[image: Screenshot of recent reputation history]

From May 6, 25 reputation are counted (see highlight color). Result should be:

```
70+35+10+60+20+0+120+30+25 = 370
```

Actual result on the badge is:

```
399
```

The difference seems to come from:

```
+1 removed (May 8)
-10 removed (May 9)
-20 removed (May 9)
```

Comment: Stop *(keep)* finding bugs! You're making Super User have low self esteem. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional - that's a very denormalized value that's actually trigger based in the DB.  We can only (sanely) show one flavor of the number, we chose to go with the default ("show remove posts" unchecked) value.

Storing the other for this rare case just isn't worth maintaining - it's too rare and doesn't matter that much, since it is correct in the default view.